# Hiding single class in ArcGIS Pro legend?

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend

How do I hide a specific feature in my legend?

The feature River is shown on the map but should be hidden in the legend. The other features are in the same layer.

The only way I can think of is to duplicate the layer, separate the features and not showing the layer with the river features. However, I assume there must be a better way to do this.

[image]

Comment: Duplicating the layer and removing the class you don't want is the way I've always done it but I would add an extra, you don't want to draw the layer twice so add a definition query to the duplicated layer with the symbol class removed FID = -1 (or OBJECTID = -1) to ensure no features are drawn on the map twice.

Comment: Convert to graphics, ungroup, delete item, move lower part up.

Comment: That works too @FelixIP but you'll always get *'just one more change'* at the last minute, when the legend is converted to graphics it no longer updates to the current symbology. Of course if you're using a duplicate layer you would need to remember to import the symbology and re-delete the one you don't want - either method is just as problematic with last minute changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still hope that there might be a built-in solution by ArcGIS Pro. This is the solution I have so far:

- Duplicate the layer
- The first layer shows River feature
- The second layer shows all other features

[Michael Stimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15054/michael-stimson) suggest using a definition query in addition to avoid that the layer is not painted twice. [FelixIP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/34531/felixip) suggest to convert the legend to a graphics and delete the item. (see comments in question)